# Which filter to use in weka to use k means clustering on categorical data?

Tags: cluster-analysis, k-means

Which pre processing filter I should use in weka to apply k means to work for the records with attributes that are not quantitative but categorical in nature. For example  three records with not quantitative attributes of Income Level with values of {low, medium, high}, Married with values of {yes, no} and State of Residence with values of {Alabama, Alaska,…, Wyoming}.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Many people use **one hot encoding** for this.

The results usually are rather bad, because k-means is designed for *continuous* variables. The resulting cluster centers will no longer be binary, and may not map back to categorial values well (which is not a surprise, since k-means is all about *means*, but what is the mean of "apple", "banana" and "orange")?

Usually you will get much more meaningful results if you instead look for *frequent itemsets* rather than k-means centers.